# What is the best way of accessing routes in ActiveRecord models and observers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a situation where I want to make a request to third-party API(url shortening service) after creating a record in the database (updates a column in the table which stores the short url), in order to decouple the API request from the Model, I have set up an ActiveRecord Observer which kicks in every time a record is created, using `after_create` callback hook, here is the relevant code:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class ArticleObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(model)
    url = article_url(model)
    # Make api request...
  end
end
```

The problem in the above code is `article_url` because Rails Routes are not available in either Model or ModelObservers, same as ActionMailer (similar problem exists in Mails where if we need to put an URL we have to configure "ActionMailer::default_options_url"). In theory accessing routes/request object in Model is considered a bad design. To circumvent the above issue I could include the `url_helpers` module as described in the following URL:

http://slaive-prog.tumblr.com/post/7618787555/using-routes-in-your-model-in-rails-3-0-x

But this does not seem to me a clean solution, does anybody have a pointer on this issue or any advice on how it should be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely not let your models know about your routes. Instead, add something like `attr_accessor :unshortened_url` on your `Article` class. Set that field in your controller, and then use it from your observer. This has the added benefit of continuing to work if you later decide to set your shortened URL asynchronously via a background task.

**Edit**

A couple of things, first of all.

1. Let's get the knowledge of *creating* a short_url out of the model
   entirely.
2. We could nitpick and say that the short_url itself doesn't belong in the model at all, but to remain practical let's leave it in there.

So let's move the trigger of this soon-to-be-background task into the controller.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :short_url_job, :only => [:create]

  # ...


  protected

  def short_url_job
    begin
      @article.short_url = "I have a short URL"
      @article.save!
    rescue Exception => e
      # Log thy exception here
    end
  end
end
```

Now, obviously, this version of `short_url_job` is stupid, but it illustrates the point. You could trigger a `DelayedJob`, some sort of `resque` task, or whatever at this point, and your controller will carry on from here.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution, let me try and get back to you

Comment: Well, I tried the solution but ran into an issue with generating the URL, the problem is when I try to generate the URL before saving the object(saving would cause the observer to run), the ID of the article object is "nil" hence setting the `unshortened_url = article_url(article)` throws error as expected. By the way the unshortened URL will be the article URL (will be mapped to the show action of the article controller and it requires the ID to be present :-( ). As your point of using async background job, that's what I am planning to try next instead of this observer thing

Comment: Well that's a good point. I'll think about this. I'm certain there's a better solution than giving your model knowledge that it should not have though.

Comment: I agree that my models should not have knowledge about the routes, this kind of defeats the purpose of MVC encapsulation

Comment: In fact I tried the exact same thing yesterday, only difference was I had the `delayedJob` call inside the action, now I see that it can further be refactored and moved into an `after_filter`, thanks for the insight. It also 'kind of' validates of not using ActiveRecord observers for this particular type of situations.